# CSS does not load in Django while rendering view

Tags: python, css, django, rendering, django-views

I dive into Django making blog. The problem is that after rendering view there is only text content without any CSS styles on the page. Other types of pages render properly.

This is my setup:

mysite/blog/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from blog.models import Post,Cat

def view_cat(request, slug):
    cat = get_object_or_404(Cat, slug=slug)
    return render_to_response('cats.html', {
        'cat': cat,
        'posts': Post.objects.filter(cat=cat)[:5]
    })
```

mysite/blog/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView
from blog.models import Post, Cat

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$',
    ListView.as_view(
        queryset=Post.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:10],
        template_name='index.html'
        )
    ),

url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
    DetailView.as_view(
        model=Post,
        template_name='detail.html'
        )
    ),
 url(r'^cat/(?P<slug>\w+)/$', 
    'blog.views.view_cat', 
    ),

)
```

mysite/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'',include('blog.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^about/$', 'django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template', 
{'template': 'about.html'}),
url(r'^contact/$', 'django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template', 
{'template': 'contact.html'}),
)
```

mysite/settings.py

```
# Django settings for mysite project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
# ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
) 

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
# Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql','mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': '/home/user/www/mysite/sqlite3.db',# Or path to
             database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': '',              # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '',              # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
}
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/user/www/mysite/media/'

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/user/www/mysite/static/'

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# URL prefix for admin static files -- CSS, JavaScript and images.
# Make sure to use a trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/static/admin/", "/static/admin/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
# Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '26m-1=h8m+a+s3y@tv!!3pagdcjt)0(bz)lr79%yiy8e8&0=c-'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)   

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
'/home/user/www/mysite/templates'
# Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.comments',
# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
 'django.contrib.admin',
# Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
# 'django.contrib.admindocs',
'blog',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
}
}
```

mysite/templates/cats.html (indicated in mysite/blog/views.py), CSS does not load here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Mysite.com</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Le styles -->
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
  body {
    padding-top: 60px; 
/* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
  }
</style>


<!-- Le fav and touch icons -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/apple-touch-icon.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" 
sizes="72x72" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" 
href="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">

        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="/">Mysite.com</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="/">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">

<div class="row">

<div class="span9">
<ul class="breadcrumb">
<li>
<a href="/">Home</a> <span class="divider">/</span>
</li>
<li>
<strong><a href="">{{ cat.name }}</a></strong>
</li>

</ul>




</div>
<div class="span3">
<h3>Construction progress...</h3>
<span class="label label-info">Functionality</span></p>
<div class="progress progress-info
progress-striped active">
<div class="bar"
style="width: 50%;"></div>
</div>
<span class="label label-info">Design</span></p>
<div class="progress progress-info
progress-striped active">
<div class="bar"
style="width: 30%;"></div>
</div>
<span class="label label-info">Usability</span></p>
<div class="progress progress-info
progress-striped active">
<div class="bar"
style="width: 5%;"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div> <!-- /container -->

<!-- Le javascript
================================================== -->

<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

mysite/templates/index.html (for example), CSS loads here but there are only few differences between cats.html and index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Mysite.com</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      body {
        padding-top: 60px; 
 /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
      }
    </style>


    <!-- Le fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/apple-touch-icon.png">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" 
href="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" 
     sizes="114x114" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">

            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="brand" href="/">Mysite.com</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="/">Blog</a></li>
              <li><a href='/about'>About</a></li>
              <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>

            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
<div class="row">

<div class="span9">

{% if post_list %}

    {% for post in post_list %}
        <strong><a href="/{{ post.id }}/">{{ post.title }}</a></strong> at 
<a href="/cat/{{post.cat.slug}}/">{{post.cat}}</a></p>
        <p>{{ post.body }} <a href="/{{ post.id }}/">read more</a></p>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}

{% else %}

    <p>No posts are available.</p>

{% endif %}
</div>
<div class="span3">
<h3>Construction progress...</h3>
<span class="label label-info">Functionality</span></p>
    <div class="progress progress-info
    progress-striped active">
    <div class="bar"
    style="width: 50%;"></div>
    </div>
    <span class="label label-info">Design</span></p>
    <div class="progress progress-info
    progress-striped active">
    <div class="bar"
    style="width: 30%;"></div>
    </div>
    <span class="label label-info">Usability</span></p>
    <div class="progress progress-info
    progress-striped active">
    <div class="bar"
    style="width: 5%;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->

    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I think there is a mistake in blog/views.py or/and blog/urls.py, because when i delete django code from cats.html, the situation stays the same: there is only rendered text without any styles when i go to www.mysite.com/cat/asfas/

(yeah, asfas is a real slug of category)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the `{{ STATIC_URL }}` tag to work in your templates, you need to render your templates with a `RequestContext`. Your generic views take care of this automatically.

When you use the [`render_to_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) shortcut in your `view_cat` view, you have to include the context instance manually. At the moment you are not using `RequestContext`, so the `{{ static_url }}` tag doesn't work. This breaks the links to your stylesheets, so you don't see the correct styling.

Here's how to include `RequestContext` in your view:

```
return render_to_response('cats.html', {
    'cat': cat,
    'posts': Post.objects.filter(cat=cat)[:5]
},
context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Alternatively, if you're using Django 1.3 or later, you can use the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut instead:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
...
    return render(request, 'cats.html', {        
        'cat': cat,
        'posts': Post.objects.filter(cat=cat)[:5]
    })
```

Comment: I also wanted to ask if it is possible to convert view_cat into generic one to have everything in one place (urls.py). Or it is better to have such kind of views in view.py?

Comment: That's a separate question really. You can't use any of the generic views directly in your urls, but you could subclass `ListView` (see the [dynamic filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#dynamic-filtering) example in the Django docs). Where you keep your view functions and classes is up to you. It can be tempting to include really simple views in urls.py, but as your project grows in size, it's more organized to keep the views in their own module.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you also need to pass the request object to the render shortcut.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
...
    return render(request, 'cats.html', {
        'cat': cat,
        'posts': Post.objects.filter(cat=cat)[:5]
    })
```

Comment: Bit late, but I've fixed the `render` example in my answer now.